# Static methods for recursive functions within a class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working with nested dictionaries on Python (2.7) obtained from YAML objects and I have a couple of questions that I've been trying to get an answer to by reading, but have not been successful. I'm somewhat new to Python.

One of the simplest functions is one that reads the whole dictionary and outputs a list of all the keys that exist in it. I use an underscore at the beginning since this function is later used by others within a class.

```py
    class Myclass(object):

    @staticmethod
    def _get_key_list(d,keylist):
        for key,value in d.iteritems():
            keylist.append(key)
            if isinstance(value,dict):
                Myclass._get_key_list(d.get(key),keylist)
        return list(set(keylist))

    def diff(self,dict2):
        keylist = []
        all_keys1 = self._get_key_list(self.d,keylist)
        all_keys2 = self._get_key_list(dict2,keylist)
        ... # More code
```

Question 1: Is this a correct way to do this? I am not sure whether it's good practice to use a static method for this reason. Since `self._get_key_list(d,keylist)` is recursive, I dont want "self" to be the first argument once the function is recursively called, which is what would happen for a regular instance method.

I have a bunch of static methods that I'm using, but I've read in a lot of places thay they could perhaps not be good practice when used a lot. I also thought I could make them module functions, but I wanted them to be tied to the class.

Question 2: Instead of passing the argument `keylist` to `self._get_key_list(d,keylist)`, how can I initialize an empty list inside the recursive function and update it? Initializing it inside would reset it to [] every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would eliminate `keylist` as an explicit argument:

```
def _get_keys(d):
    keyset = set()
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        keylist.add(key)
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            keylist.update(_get_key_list(value))
    return keyset
```

Let the caller convert the set to a list if they really need a list, rather than an iterable.

Often, there is little reason to declare something as a static method rather than a function outside the class.

If you are concerned about efficiency (e.g., getting lots of repeat keys from a dict), you can go back to threading a single set/list through the calls as an explicit argument, but don't make it optional; just require that the initial caller supply the set/list to update. To emphasize that the second argument will be mutated, just return `None` when the function returns.

```
def _get_keys(d, result):
    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        result.add(key)
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            _get_keys(value, result)

result = set()
_get_keys(d1, result)
_get_keys(d2, result)
# etc
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely use sets directly.

Comment: So, even if it's a "private" method that will be used by other instance methods from that class only, does it seem OK to write it outside the class? I'll be later importing this class to another file.

Comment: If there's nothing particularly unique to the class about the function, make it a function. At the very least, it is easier to refer to a function than a method.

Answer (score 0):

There's no good reason to make a recursive function in a class a static method unless it is meant to be invoked outside the context of an instance.

To initialize a parameter, we usually assign to it a default value in the parameter list, but in case it needs to be a mutable object such as an empty list in this case, you need to default it to None and the initialize it inside the function, so that the list reference won't get reused in the next call:

```
class Myclass(object):
    def _get_key_list(self, d, keylist=None):
        if keylist is None:
            keylist = []
        for key, value in d.iteritems():
            keylist.append(key)
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                self._get_key_list(d.get(key), keylist)
        return list(set(keylist))

    def diff(self, dict2):
        all_keys1 = self._get_key_list(self.d)
        all_keys2 = self._get_key_list(dict2)
        ...  # More code
```

Comment: Making the default value of `keylist` a list makes `keylist` be the same list across *all* initial calls.

Comment: No, the default value will be used only if `keylist` isn't supplied as the second argument to `_get_key_list`.

Comment: @blhsing What is the purpose of `self` if you are not even using the object itself? It confuses me a bit.

Comment: @blhsing Once you add something to the default value, though, it *stays* there; you don't get a fresh empty list on every call that doesn't take an explicit argument.

Comment: @chepner And that's exactly what the OP wants. Only during recursion that we want to pass on the updated `keylist` to the next level of `_get_key_list`.

Comment: And the second time you call `_get_key_list` explicitly?

Comment: @chepner Yes, because the second call and the first call are independent of each other.

Comment: No, they aren't, because you've *modified* the default value for `keylist`.

Comment: @chepner What are you talking about? There's no such thing as modifying the default value of a parameter. `all_keys1 = self._get_key_list(self.d)` does not do anything to change the default value of `_get_key_list`.

Comment: @chepner I stand corrected. I forgot about such basics. I've edited my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @CAP I've corrected my answer accordingly after chepner correctly pointed out the issue with using a mutable object as a default value.

Comment: @cheapner Thanks for pointing the problem of bhsing previous solution. I learnt this error the hard way.

Comment: @CAP Even though it doesn't make use of `self`, it does not make sense to make it a static function because it does not appear to be called outside the class.